# Why doesn't my app have any code under the (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *) in the appDelegate?

Tags: ios, methods, appdelegate

As far as I know when I open the AppDelegate.m file it should have code that resembles this in it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" 
bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return yes;
```

But when I open mine it only has the comment in there and the

```
return yes;
```

Also, when I input all that code manually it tells me for the  self.viewController line that the property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *' and also against 2 lines below it for the next instance of self.viewController.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you created your project with a storyboard (which has been the only option for a while now), you don't need that code.  `UIApplicationMain` creates your `UIWindow`, assigns it to your application delegate's `window` property, and loads the window's root view controller from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you select Project Template other then "`Empty Application`", `Xcode` will create project as default `Storyboard` Application.

Check if you have `Main.storyboard` in your app. if You want to add `UIViewController` manually try creating Application with Project Template "`Empty Application`" and then add New `Objective C` File (`UIViewController` with `xib`) to project and add the following code.

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```